# How to get some original json fields after mapping geo-point with python Elasticsearch?

Tags: python, json, elasticsearch

I'm tying to get some original data with geo-point mapping. I need to get satname and timestamp alone with "geo"

I get data from Restful API with python Elasticsearch.

```
settings = { "settings": {
                 "number_of_shards":1,
                  'number_of_replicas':0
                 },
      "mappings" : { 
           "document" : {
                "properties":{
                    "geo": {
                       "type": "geo_point"
                            }
                          }
                        } 
                     } 
                  }

es.indices.create(index = "new", body=settings)

def collect_data():
  data = requests.get(url = URL).json() 
  del data['positions'][1]

  new_data = {'geo':{'lat':data['positions'][0]['satlatitude'],
               'lon':data['positions'][0]['satlongitude']}}, {data['info'][0]['satname']} ,   
                {data['positions'][0]['timestamp']} 



 es.index(index='new', doc_type='document', body=new_data)
schedule.every(10).seconds.do(collect_data)


while True:
 schedule.run_pending()
 time.sleep(1) 

Error received:
SerializationError: (({'geo': {'lat': 37.43662067, 'lon': -26.09384821}}, {1591391688}), 
TypeError("Unable to serialize {1591391688} (type: <class 'set'>)"))
```

RESTful json data sample--- {'info': {'satname': 'SPACE STATION', 'satid': 25544,
   'transactionscount': 0}, 'positions': [{'satlatitude': 28.89539607,
   'satlongitude': 90.44547739, 'sataltitude': 420.36, 'azimuth': 12.46,
   'elevation': -52.81, 'ra': 215.55022984, 'dec': -5.00234017, 'timestamp': 1591196844, 'eclipsed':
    True}]}

I need to have "geo", "satnam" and"timestamp".I'm wondering how could I obtain correct results.

Comment: do you ever get more than one position in the response? I think the issue here is you need to change `{data['positions'][0]['timestamp']}` to `'timestamp': data['positions'][0]['timestamp']}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you were setting the timestamp and satname without a key, try this to process the data:

```
import json
from datetime import datetime

response_json = '''
{
    "info": {
        "satname": "SPACE STATION",
        "satid": 25544,
        "transactionscount": 0
    },
    "positions": [
        {
            "satlatitude": 28.89539607,
            "satlongitude": 90.44547739,
            "sataltitude": 420.36,
            "azimuth": 12.46,
            "elevation": -52.81,
            "ra": 215.55022984,
            "dec": -5.00234017,
            "timestamp": 1591196844,
            "eclipsed": true
        }
    ]
}
'''

response_data = json.loads(response_json)



def process_data(data):
    return {
        'satname': response_data['info']['satname'],
        # comvert unix timestamp to iso time
        'timestamp': datetime.fromtimestamp(response_data['positions'][0]['timestamp']).isoformat(),
        'geo': {
            'lat': response_data['positions'][0]['satlatitude'],
            'lon': response_data['positions'][0]['satlongitude']
        }
    }

print(process_data(response_data))
```

Output:

```
{'satname': 'SPACE STATION', 'timestamp': '2020-06-03T15:07:24', 'geo': {'lat': 28.89539607, 'lon': 90.44547739}}
```

Comment: as I stream data from a website ( I mentioned this data is coming from RESTful API) so data change every 10 seconds.  Is it possible to be the data every time as you specify there? Actually I streaming data. I updated d my code with my complete coding to better understand what I'm doing.

Comment: I used static data just to get the correct json format in and out. you can use this `process_data()` function in your code and replace your `new_data = ...` line with `new_data = process_data(data)`

Comment: @user according to your error, the issue was just with your dictionary definition formatting

Comment: Yes you're correct!!. And I followed both of your ways..There are working.Thanks.Please just little clarification, if I need to convert this UNIX timestamp, do I have to add "date": {
        "type":   "date",
        "format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss||yyyy-MM-dd||epoch_millis" to mapping? I don't know under "properties" I can have many mappings?

Comment: `from datetime import datetime` and `'timestamp': datetime.fromtimestamp(response_data['positions'][0]['timestamp']).isoformat(),` should get you iso time instead of unix timestamp. Edited to reflect

Comment: It went fine,many thanks for the help. But still I'm confusing the mapping concept. why we only do mapping on geo-point rather timestamp? For timestamp we just convert "int" data type  to "timstamp" what we usually do. Pls can you explain me?

Comment: You could get rid of the geo tag and have lat and lon on the same level on the same level as satname and timestamp